# Summernote upload file to server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, summernote

I am currently do following instruction to process image upload from summernote control in ASP.NET MVC Razor.

**Server code:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var imageUrl = UpdateProfilePicture(file);
        return Json(imageUrl);
    }
```

And
**Client side ajax:**

```
<script>
$('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 200,
    focus: true, onImageUpload: function (files, editor, welEditable) {
        sendFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
    }
});
function sendFile(file, editor, welEditable) {

    console.log(file);
    $.ajax({
        data: {file:file},
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("UploadImage","Message")",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (url) {
            editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);
        }
    });
}
```

I got a result at server side method, but parameter `HttpPostedFileBase file` is null

some examples says that works, but my code doesn't work functionally !

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: What is the reault of your console.log(file)?  I think that value can't be correctly translated into HttpPostedFileBase

Answer (score 0):

In your method use "Request" object to get file like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public string UploadImage()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return YOUR UPLOADED IMAGE URL;
    }
```